# Table does not render correctly - Markdown Github

Tags: github, markdown, tabular, readme

My github readme table does not render in the correct way. I use this:

````
Request options:
| Option | Description |
| --- | --- |
| url | Request url |
| method | ```'get'``` \| ```'post'``` \| ```'put'``` \| ```'delete'``` - (default: ```'get'```) |
| headers | optional array: ```[{name: string, value: string}]``` |
| body | Request body (any type) |
| responseType | ```'text'``` \| ```'json'``` - (defult: ```'text'```) |
| success | Success function - ```function(data) { }``` |
| error | Error function - ```function(err) { }``` |
````

But render this:

[image: Table Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it sorted out. I should have a line between "Request Options" and the table.

````
Request options:

| Option | Description |
| --- | --- |
| url | Request url |
| method | ```'get'``` \| ```'post'``` \| ```'put'``` \| ```'delete'``` - (default: ```'get'```) |
| headers | optional array: ```[{name: string, value: string}]``` |
| body | Request body (any type) |
| responseType | ```'text'``` \| ```'json'``` - (defult: ```'text'```) |
| success | Success function - ```function(data) { }``` |
| error | Error function - ```function(err) { }``` |
````

Comment: btw, it's much nicer and easier to see your errors when you align all the column dividers by adding more spaces..